# Ajax call returns 200 but considered as error

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets

I am trying to do a simple call to a servlet in ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://myserver/c/myfunction',
    cache : false,
    data: {key: 'value'},
    success:function(){
        alert("success");
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

with my servlet function in java :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/c/myfunction", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public synchronized void myfunction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

I get a status code 200 OK, but I still see the "error" alert. Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you check your browser console? Also, you're not sending back anything, which is probably what causes the error.

Comment: It seems to happen because I use two different servers : "has been blocked by CORS policy". How should I solve that in my case ?

Comment: Allow Cors headers in your backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question by simply looking at my console...
It said `request has been blocked by CORS policy`.

So I had to add `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` to my java code to make it work.